# Get the titles of the nodes whose node IDs are contained in a field

Tags: 6, entities

```
$attr = explode(",", $node->field_xlnum[0]['value']);
```

`$node->field_xlnum[0]['value']` contains `20,4,56,987,68,96`, where each value is a node ID.
I want to get all the titles, and output them in an HTML list. How do I do it?

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
$attr = explode(",", $node->field_xlnum[0]['value']);
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE nid IN ($attr) AND type = %s order by created DESC", test);
while(($items = db_fetch_object($result)) { 
  $output = theme_item_list($items, array('class'=>'tabs primary'));
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on what tostinni posted, this is what worked for me. I also added the `$title` parameter. It's supposed to be the second parameter, and if you leave it out, the `array('class'=>'tabs primary')` would be used as the second parameter instead, which wouldn't work quite right. I simplified the query a little since I don't have a content type called 'test,' but you can put that in easily:

```
// the $attr should be a string
$attr = $node->field_xlnum[0]['value'];
// $attr put into a placeholder
$result = db_query("SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE nid in (%s) order by created DESC", $attr);

/*** 
  * if you put theme_item_list into the while loop, 
  *  it will create separate lists for each item,
  * instead of adding 'li's to one ul, as I'm assuming you want?
  */
while($items=db_fetch_object($result)){
// put the title strings into an array
    $list[] = $items->title;
}
// including the $title parameter - if not needed, you can change to $title = NULL
$output = theme_item_list($list, $title = 'A list', 'ul class="tabs primary"');
echo $output;
```

Comment: `while($items=db_fetch_object($result)){
// put the title strings into an array
    $list[] = $items->title;
}` should be enough. No need for `$i`.

Comment: For sure - edited to remove `$i` incrementer.

Answer (score 3):

A few remarks:

1. You said that `$node->field_xlnum[0]['value']` contains a list of nid separated by comas so you don't need to explode it in order to use them in a IN clause. If you do so, $attr will be an Array().
2. You put `test` as an argument in your query, isn't this a variable `$test` or a string `'test'`
3. You should better use [db_placeholders](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.inc/function/db_placeholders/6) for putting multiples values inside a IN.

   ```
   $attr = explode(",", $node->field_xlnum[0]['value']);
   db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title
     FROM {node} n
     WHERE n.nid IN (" . db_placeholders($attr, 'int') . ")
     AND type = %s 
     ORDER BY n.created DESC", $data, 'test'
   );
   ```